# Custom Line Chart Possible in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, canvas, chart.js

I hope you are having amazing day I wanted to ask how we can achieve this kind of advance chart in react native.there are few chart libararies but they don't provide customisation to that extent.The app i recorded is Webull.If anyone can guide.I'll be very thankful.
https://imgur.com/a/dMZrkFP

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts) This library has aged like wine and it keeps adding new features on demand. This library already has a feature called [pointerCofig](https://github.com/Abhinandan-Kushwaha/react-native-gifted-charts/blob/master/docs/LineChart/LineChartProps.md#pointerconfig) which can be used to achieve your required chart.

[image: chart with pointer]

The code for the above chart can be found [here in the official documentation.](https://gifted-charts.web.app/areachart)